# How can I configure Angular Material drag and drop to allow dropping an element when the cursor is outside the drop zone

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

How can I configure Angular Material drag and drop to allow dropping an element when the cursor is outside the drop zone, but the draggable element is still inside?

[The element is only dropped when the cursor is inside the drop zone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hofie.gif)